# i want to format date ,i have "2019-06-30T23:00:00" this format and i want to display 6/30,so how to format?

Tags: xamarin-forms-4

I want to format a date in xamarin form ,I have "2019-06-30T23:00:00"
this format ,I want to convert it to 6/30 ,
so how to convert .

I  tried  in xaml file with string format `StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM}'}`
but nothing is working from xaml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fast and simple workaround try this:

```
string str = "2019-06-30T23:00:00"; // code that gives you time
str = str.Substring(5,2)+"/"+str.Substring(8,2));
```

If you need better solution please specify how you retrieve the time.

Comment: thanks it works ,but can u tell me how can i do this in xaml file .

Comment: i am doing like this but its not working                       Text="{Binding Path= lastPostDate,StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"

Comment: Unfortunately my search was unsuccessful. As I have no environment to try it right now, I can't say you what exactly is wrong. Sorry.